# How hard would it be for Santa to give a present to one child?

Tags: santa-claus, economy

Santa has to start getting ready for Christmas 2018, and that means he needs a budget.

Now, you might assume that this will require [billions of dollars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/100635/8914). But that assumes that every child is either on the nice list or the naughty list. In reality, usually only two or three children make the nice list, and a dozen or so make the naughty list. Delivering to *all* the children would be insane, and also inane, given how mediocre most children are. For the purposes of this question, we will only focus one delivering to one child.

Notes:

- The sleigh and reindeer are as efficient (in terms of chemical energy) and fast as a jet, but are fueled with reindeer food instead of petroluem.
- We'll assume the child lives at the equator.
- Santa maintains a base at the North Pole. Usually only ten people (including elves) are at this base at a time, as well as the sleigh and nine reindeer.
- Santa's workshop is also stationed at the base, and requires resources similar to a research laboratory to maintain (like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_research_stations_in_the_Arctic)).
- It only takes about 72 elf-hours of labor to make a present (the child will get one present). The raw materials are basically worthless, but the end product is a powerful magical artifact. Magical elf labor normally has similar costs to that of an attorney, but they charge Santa only a tenth of the price for Christmas related services.

**Given these requirements, what would be the total costs to deliver to this one child?**

Comment: There is a massive variance in the cost of an attorney.

Comment: @sphennings uhm, we'll say that it's the average

Comment: So you want to know the combined cost of an airline ticket around half the globe and a lawyer for 72 / 8 = 9 days. That's fifteen thousand. Happy?

Comment: I don't agree with the off-topic close votes, for the same reasons I outlined [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5712/627).

Comment: @Karl don't forget artic base and breaking and entering. Also, reindeer food has a different cost then petroleum

Comment: Wouldn't you just use the maths used in all the other Santa cost topics, just reduce the elves, children and trip distance or what not down to the numbers you want? [link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/100634/santa-is-broke-how-much-does-it-cost-for-someone-else-to-be-santa/100635#100635)

Comment: @Shadowzee you can't just "reduce" it. Economics doesn't scale that way.

Comment: I, unfortunately, disagree with your disagreement about closure. This question (as evidenced by the answer) is borderline pure math. Everything was google-able with minimal effort followed by some multiplication, division, and addition.

Answer (score 4):

### Distance & Time

The duration and distance from Equator to North Pole ...
[12 hours, 7 minutes (approximate for a direct flight)](https://www.flight-durations.com/Equator-to-North-Pole)
Or, roughly a day for round trip.

### Reindeer Feed

Hummingbirds eat about half their body weight a day, so that can function as a basis for consumption.
Average, male reindeer weight `375 lbs. x 8 Reindeer = 3000 lbs.`
Half body weight = `1500 lbs.`
[½ Ton (or 2000 lbs.) of Deer Feed is `$649.99`](http://www.cabelas.com/product/Ani-Logics-Supplement-Bulk/2013272.uts?productVariantId=4211036)
So …
About `$487.49` for 0.375 Ton of Reindeer feed.

### Elf Salary

[Conservative, average, hourly cost of attorney](https://www.upcounsel.com/how-much-does-a-lawyer-cost) = `$200`
Elf salary `$200 / 10 = $20`
Hours worked `72 x $20 = $1,440`

### Result

`$487.49 + $1,440 =` **$1,927.49**

Comment: And the cost of the toy itself...

Comment: As per the original text, the toy itself is comprised of "basically" worthless materials. So it's "basically" $0.00. Notwithstanding the labor cost of chopping and shaping lumber, mining and smelting metals, mixing and moulding rubber and plastic... All done by, what, 8 or so elves...